# Windows Explorer opens when I unlock my computer

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

Whenever I unlock my computer (after manually locking it to get up from my desk) I get 2 Windows Explorer windows that come up with the directory:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Not sure what's doing this or how to make it stop. It's just annoying and I am curious if anyone has any ideas to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Run "msconfig" and look for any start up entries that have similar directories.  If you don't see something there, so a search for that path in regedit and see if you find any entries there (you likely will and will need to filter through them to find anything of value).  What you are looking for is a file/shortcut that is supposed to exist in that directory but does not.  When Windows tries to open an app that it can't find, it sometimes displays the directory instead.

Comment: Great ideas, thanks, i have to wait until i can restart to find out if it worked.